# How to access Cloud Run service IPs from Terraform / Pulumi to dynamically create A records?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, pulumi

I am using Google Cloud Run with Pulumi (similar to Terraform). My setup for Cloud Run's domain mapping is:

```typescript
  new gcp.cloudrun.DomainMapping(
    `${prefix}-domain-mapping`,
    {
      location,
      name: 'xxx',
      metadata: {
        namespace: projectId,
      },
      spec: {
        routeName: appService.name,
      },
    },
    {
      dependsOn: [appService],
    },
  )
```

Where `appService` points to an instance of Cloud Run service. This successfully creates a domain mapping to the Cloud Run service.

Next I am setting up a DNS zone with records:

```typescript
  const zone = new gcp.dns.ManagedZone(`${prefix}-zone`, {
    name: `${prefix}-zone`,
    dnsName: 'xxx.',
    visibility: 'public',
  })

  const ips = ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']
  new gcp.dns.RecordSet(
    `${prefix}-a-records`,
    {
      name: 'xxx.',
      managedZone: zone.name,
      type: 'A',
      ttl: 3600,
      rrdatas: ips,
    },
    {
      dependsOn: [zone],
      deleteBeforeReplace: true,
    },
  )
```

The code above works. I have a DNS zone with four A records pointing to 4 different IP-addresses, which point to a Cloud Run service. My problem is this: how do I automate the IPs, which I have hard-coded above? I want the IP-addresses of Cloud Run to be dynamically set for the A records. The `ips` variable has to point to the Cloud Run instance's IPs, but I can't find a way to do that.

Or perhaps I'm doing this all wrong and there's another way this should be done? My goal is that if the Cloud Run service is updated and receives new IPs, the DNS records should be automatically updated as well. I don't want to manually update addresses.

Since Pulumi is more or less equivalent to Terraform, answers in either Terraform or Pulumi are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you mapping a DNS Zone (root domain) or a subdomain of a DNS Zone? For the first case, Cloud Run provides an IP address for an A record. For the second case, Cloud Run provides a DNS name for a CNAME record.

Comment: I'm mapping a root domain. I can get the IPs from the Cloud Run domain mapping table, but I want that to be automated.

Comment: If you assign `DomainMapping` to a `mapping` variable, won't `mapping.resourceRecords` contain what you need?

Comment: It has a list of records, which have the rrdatas field. However, those records won't be available at the point of running the Pulumi automation. And the API won't accept resourceRecords for the rrdatas field in RecordSet.

Comment: They will be available during the Pulumi run -- after the `DomainMapping` resource is created but before the `RecordSet` is created -- and you can assign it, that's why `rrdatas` has `Input` type, not just string array.

Comment: @MikhailShilkov `rrdatas: mapping.status.resourceRecords` does not type check. `rrdatas` expects `pulumi.Input<pulumi.Input<string>[]>`, but `resourceRecords` is `outputs.cloudrun.DomainMappingStatusResourceRecord[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried running this but at least this code compiles:

```typescript
const mapping = new gcp.cloudrun.DomainMapping(...);

const records = mapping.status.resourceRecords?.apply(rs => rs ?? []) ?? pulumi.output([]);

new gcp.dns.RecordSet(`${prefix}-a-records`, {
    name: 'xxx.',
    managedZone: zone.name,
    type: 'A',
    ttl: 3600,
    rrdatas: records.apply(rs => rs.map(r => r.rrdata)),
}, {
    dependsOn: [zone, mapping],
    deleteBeforeReplace: true,
});
```

The dance with `records` is there to get rid of `undefined` on two levels... Not sure if it can be simplified.

Comment: This worked well. I wasn't aware of `apply` function. It kind of lets me do an "inner map". I also used it to inner filter the array to only have A-records for the A RecordSet. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime you have a question about `Output` or `Input`, `apply` is usually the answer. Be sure to study https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#outputs

Answer (score 7):

Since this question is tagged with both Pulumi *and* Terraform tags, here's a possible Terraform solution:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "example" {
  location = "us-central1"
  name     = "xxx"

  metadata {
    namespace = local.project_name
  }

  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_service.app.name
  }
}

resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "example" {
  name       = "${local.prefix}-zone"
  dns_name   = "xxx."
  visibility = "public"
}

locals {
  dns_records = {
    "A" = [
      for rr in google_cloud_run_domain_mapping.example.resource_records :
      rr.rrdata if rr.type == "A"
    ]
    "AAAA" = [
      for rr in google_cloud_run_domain_mapping.example.resource_records :
      rr.rrdata if rr.type == "AAAA"
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "example" {
  for_each = local.dns_records

  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.example.name

  name    = "xxx."
  type    = each.key
  ttl     = 3600
  rrdatas = each.value
}
```

Comment: I think the resource you need to iterate over is `google_cloud_run_domain_mapping.example.status[0].resource_records`.

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue but more complicated, with for each involved. This is how we solved the issue

```
locals {
  regional_configs_map = {for regional_config in var.regional_configs:  regional_config.region => regional_config}
}

resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "cloudrun_mapping" {
  for_each = var.create_external_lb == false ? local.regional_configs_map : {}
  location = "${each.value.region}"
  name     = "acrossable.com"

  metadata {
    namespace = var.project
  }

  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_service.cloud_run_service[each.key].name
  }
}


locals {
  dns_records = { for key, item in local.regional_configs_map :
    "${key}" => {
      "A" = [
        for rr in google_cloud_run_domain_mapping.cloudrun_mapping[key].status[0].resource_records :
        rr.rrdata if rr.type == "A"
      ]
      "AAAA" = [
        for rr in google_cloud_run_domain_mapping.cloudrun_mapping[key].status[0].resource_records :
        rr.rrdata if rr.type == "AAAA"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "dns_cloudrun_a" {
  for_each = var.create_external_lb == false ? local.regional_configs_map : {}

  project = var.dns_project
  name    = "${each.value.domain}."
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 300

  managed_zone = var.dns_zone

  rrdatas = local.dns_records[each.key]["A"]
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "dns_cloudrun_4a" {
  for_each = var.create_external_lb == false ? local.regional_configs_map : {}

  project = var.dns_project
  name    = "${each.value.domain}."
  type    = "AAAA"
  ttl     = 300

  managed_zone = var.dns_zone

  rrdatas = local.dns_records[each.key]["AAAA"]
}
```